# How to test a C program with multiple inputs?

Tags: c, ubuntu, testing, input, terminal

I have Linux Ubuntu, and I want to test my program, for which someone gave me .txt file of multiple inputs. Now I want to run this program with inputs written in the .txt file. Theres a lot of inputs so I dont want to input them by hand. Is there some command in Linux Terminal to run a C with inputs written in a file?
thank you for your answers

Comment: Have a loop in your code that uses scanf to read each input in the textfile line by line. Try `./main < input.txt` where `./main` is your executable

Comment: `man bash`. ...

Comment: One text file contains different inputs, and you want to run your program one time for each input? How are the inputs separated in the text file? Does your program take these "inputs" on the command line or from standard input?

Comment: it takes them from standard inputs and each input is in its own line in .txt file

Answer (score 3):

I think you are suffering from the all too common misunderstanding that "standard input" == "a keyboard".  Stop thinking that.  If you've already written a program that reads from stdin, all you need to do is associate your text file with stdin.  In the shell, you do that with a redirection operator:

```
./a.out < input.txt
```

If you have multiple inputs, you can easily invoke your program on each individually:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    echo "Running on input: $file"
    ./a.out < "$file"
done
```

or you can run your program once on all the inputs:

```
cat *.txt | ./a.out
```

There are many, many ways to do what you want, and a lot of flexibility to do different things.  You'll probably want to compare the output of your program with the expected output and then you're on your way to writing a full-fledged test suite.   For example:

```
if ! ./a.out < input.txt | cmp expected-output -; then
    echo "TEST FAILED" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: yes i tried the first one but it says bash:  ./a.out: Permission denied, what do i do now?

Comment: Check the permissions on your files.  From the error message, I'd guess you need to do `chmod +x a.out`.

Comment: what is a.out? is this my c program?

Comment: `a.out` is the default name of the executable produced by many compilers if you do not give a name.  You should replace it with whatever name you have chosen.